# Formatting YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple way to convert a string "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" to "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS" ?

For example I have

```
var date_string = "20121231023350";
```

And I would like the output as

```
new_date_string = "2012/12/31 02:33:50";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"20121231023350".replace(
    /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,
    "$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6");  // "2012/12/31 02:33:50"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function ConvertTime(OldTime)
{
    if(OldTime.length != 14)
        return "Error";

    return OldTime.substring(0,4) + "/" + OldTime.substring(4,6) + "/" + OldTime.substring(6,8) + " " + OldTime.substring(8,10) + ":" + OldTime.substring(10,12) + ":" + OldTime.substring(12,14);
}

ConvertTime("20121231023350");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a library such as [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Either of these should make date Javascript handling/parsing/formatting a doddle.